# python and pyqt5 - pass through variable once button is clicked

Tags: python, variables, button, pyqt5

I have 2 py files: my.py (this is my py created from ui - script where I have windows and input line, buttons) and vat.py (this is second script which needs to be started when pushButton_2 is clicked). I would like to run all lines from vat script but my.py needs to transfer some variables to vat.py. This is a issue - how I can do this?

my.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

#import vat

import os
import openpyxl

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QDialog, QInputDialog


global glob
glob = "empty"

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(633, 392)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon01.webp"), QtGui.QIcon.Selected, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 561, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 40, 25, 19))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 141, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 611, 81))
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        **self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.start_app)**

        self.mdiArea.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 633, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuKonwerter = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuKonwerter.setObjectName("menuKonwerter")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuKonwerter.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def browsefiles(self):
        path = "~"
        full_path = os.path.expanduser(path)
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Plik excel do zaimportowania", full_path, "Excel (*.xls *.xlsx)")
        filepath = filename[0]
        self.lineEdit.setText(filepath)

    def start_app(self):
        filepath = self.lineEdit.text()
        glob = filepath

        try:
            import vat
        except:
            infoBox = QMessageBox()  ##Message Box that doesn't run
            infoBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
            infoBox.setText("Błąd pliku!")
            infoBox.setInformativeText("Użyj rozszerzenia .xlsx.")
            infoBox.setWindowTitle("Załadowano błędny plik")
            #infoBox.setDetailedText("Detailed Text")
            #infoBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
            infoBox.setEscapeButton(QMessageBox.Close)
            infoBox.exec()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Spradzenie podatników VAT"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Uruchom"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plik wejściowy (excel):"))
        self.menuKonwerter.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Konwerter"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

vat.py

```
from my import *
print(glob)
#imp = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi.__getattribute__(lineEdit.text()) - dosent work
```

All looks fine but when I run my.py and click button2 (where as you can see I am taking path from line edit) this is not working. I see in vat.py script that "glob = empty". Of course vat.py file has more functions and doing something but I need to make all steps from vat.py file (but I need to transfer some variable. Is it possible to also make a feedback from vat to my when vat finish all steps? 
TIA

Comment: one more case: 
what if in vat.py I have function which needs to collect some data from user - I nee to open a dialog where user needs to chose something - this chose will be forwarding in vat.py file next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function in vat.py and move your code into that. That way you can import the function at the top of your script but *call* it only when you need it. You can also call it multiple times (unlike importing). And of course you can pass arguments to your function.

vat.py would look something like:

```
def vat(glob):
    print(glob)
```

In my.py you can then do:

```
from vat import vat

vat(glob)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. In vat.py I have a few functions but also piece of code (no function - some for for doing something). When I imported vat in my.py this piece of code is starting - but it should start only when button2 will be clicked.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using import to execute code upon a button event. It should always be linked to a function call as standard practice. Imports should always be at the very top of your script (except in some very rare cases, but not yours). So you need to move your raw code into a function.

Comment: What about my question regarding additonal dialog?